# In Meteor, Is there a way to use multiple helpers even if one can handle multiple arguments?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

In my meteor project, I have multiple helpers. `helper1` can handle multiple arguments but he's fine even with a single argument. The problem is I want to chain this handler with the result of another one (`helper2`), which also takes an argument (the actual user data). So I wrote the following :

`{{helper1 helper2 currentUser}}`

The problem is that `helper1` seems to get two arguments : the result of `helper2`, and the `currentUser`, which means `helper2` doesn't get the `currentHelper` argument.

I tried to use parenthesis so that everyone can get its own arguments, like that :

`{{helper1 helper2(currentUser)}}` or `{{helper1 (helper2 currentUser)}}`

Or even brackets :

`{{helper1 {{helper2 currentUser}}}}`

But I get a syntax error with all these workarounds. Is there any working way to do this ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. If I read the following link correctly, then the first helper will receive anything following its name https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md#helper-arguments

Comment: I think that there is a way that could work because {{#if helper argument}} is working. In this syntax you can see that the if statement is just a helper too. Have a look at block tags maybe you can define you own. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md#custom-block-helpers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem – using `#with`:

```
{{#with firstHelper data}}
  {{secondHelper this}}
{{/with}}
```

Comment: Note that if the result of `firstHelper data` is falsy, the contents of the `#with` block never gets evaluated.